# Assets on storage card

Tags: android, android-assets

I have an application that stores a lot of data in the assets folder (html, audio, video, etc.). I use the file:///android_assets to access these files. But due to the apk size limitation of 50 MB imposed by the market I will be migrating these files to a storage card.
Is it possible to install the application on phone memory and have the assets directory on the storage card, so that they can still be accessed using file protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since assets are part of your apk, it's not possible to separate them or move them to the sdcard. You can enable "Move to SD Card" for your app, but that doesn't help with the 50 MB market limit.

One solution would be to store the data files on the web and not include them in the apk. When your app is launched for the first time after installation, you would kick off a one-time process that downloads them to the sdcard.

Once the files are on the sdcard, you can access them with:

```
file:///sdcard/<your_directory>
```

Or to get a File reference to the sdcard root directory:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Comment: Yes,I have done the same.Moved everything to the SDCard. The data contains lot of images which are displayed in a custom list along with text. After moving this data to external storage the performance of the app has degraded. The list scroll is not as smooth as it was when the data was in the assets. Any pointers on how to improve the performance ?